# NodeToString - Java - Large files

Tags: java, dom, sax, stax

Quiero cambiar la siguiente función para hacerla funcionar con ficheros grandes. He oido hablar de SAX, StAX, pero no me aclaro como hay que hacerlo.

Os comparto la función a ver si alguien me puede ayudar

```
public static String nodeToString(Node node) throws TransformerFactoryConfigurationError, TransformerException {
        Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
        Source source = new DOMSource(node);
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(sw);
        transformer.transform(source, result);
        return sw.toString();
    }
```

Muchas gracias a todos.

Un saludo